# Applescript Occasionally Freezes Automator

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm trying to use this applescript to modify a file path written to a text file, copy the modified path to the clipboard, set it as variable thePath, use it to pull a Google Drive link from a list, and then copy that link to the clipboard.

Running it within Automator, it sometimes works perfectly but other times it stalls while running this applescript and crashes textedit, and then eventually times out without any specific error messages.  Are there any issues with my code that would be causing Automator to freeze?

Note that I've substituted the actual links with link1, link2, etc. for privacy reasons.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    tell application "TextEdit" to activate
    
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 125
        key code 123 using shift down
        key code 123 using shift down
        key code 123 using shift down
        key code 123 using shift down
        key code 123 using shift down
        key code 123 using shift down
        key code 123 using shift down
        key code 123 using shift down
        keystroke "x" using command down
        keystroke "a" using command down
        key code 51
        keystroke "v" using command down
        keystroke "s" using command down
        keystroke "w" using command down
        
        delay 2
        
        
    end tell
    
    
    set thePath to the clipboard
    
    set myList to {"link1","link2","link3","link4","link5","link6","link7","link8","link9","link10","link11","link12","link13","link14","link15","link16","link17","link18","link19","link20","link21","link22","link23","link24","link25","link26","link27","link28","link29","link30","link31","link32","link33","link34","link35","link36","link37","link38","link39","link40","link41","link42","link43","link44","link45","link46","link47","link48","link49","link50","link51","link52","link53","link54","link55","link56","link57","link58","link59","link60","link61","link62","link63","link64","link65","link66","link67","link68","link69","link70","link71","link72","link73","link74","link75","link76","link77","link78","link79","link80","link81","link82","link83","link84","link85","link86","link87","link88","link89","link90","link91","link92","link93","link94","link95","link96","link97","link98","link99","link100","link101","link102","link103","link104","link105","link106","link107","link108","link109","link110","link111","link112","link113","link114","link115","link116","link117","link118","link119","link120","link121","link122","link123","link124","link125","link126","link127","link128","link129","link130","link131","link132","link133","link134","link135","link136","link137","link138","link139","link140","link141","link142","link143","link144","link145","link146","link147","link148","link149","link150","link151","link152","link153","link154","link155","link156","link157","link158","link159","link160","link161","link162","link163","link164","link165","link166","link167","link168","link169","link170","link171","link172","link173","link174","link175","link176","link177","link178","link179","link180","link181","link182","link183","link184","link185","link186","link187","link188","link189","link190","link191","link192","link193","link194","link195","link196","link197","link198","link199","link200","link201","link202","link203","link204","link205","link206","link207","link208","link209","link210","link211","link212","link213","link214","link215","link216","link217","link218","link219","link220","link221","link222","link223","link224","link225","link226","link227","link228","link229","link230","link231","link232","link233","link234","link235","link236","link237","link238","link239","link240","link241","link242","link243","link244","link245","link246","link247","link248","link249","link250","link251","link252","link253","link254","link255","link256","link257","link258","link259","link260","link261","link262","link263","link264","link265","link266","link267","link268","link269","link270","link271","link272","link273","link274","link275","link276","link277","link278","link279","link280","link281","link282","link283","link284","link285","link286","link287","link288","link289","link290","link291","link292","link293","link294","link295","link296","link297","link298"}
    
    set the clipboard to item thePath of myList
    
    
    
    return input
end run
```

Comment: UI scripting is fragile. If anything changes the focus then the script could be disrupted. I don't really like using it and generally assume that there is a fair amount of undefined behaviour taking place. It would be difficult to ascertain the issue without knowing where exactly the script fails. That said, does the text file have only a single file path on a single line (i.e. no line endings at all, no anything else at all)? Can you provide (make up) some example data that would work? A file path, a list of three links, etc…. I'd like to see what gets selected and deleted and passed on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The text file is a single line with a file path (/Users/robdavis/Desktop/!Moms/GDrive Sync/GuestFolders/00000007) and the UI script is simply removing everything but the last folder number (00000007).  I'm new to applescript and was struggling to pass variables between automator and applescript but as I'm doing more research, I'm thinking this would be better accomplished by simply finding and replacing the text with applescript and not using the textedit script.

Comment: I think that would be a simpler and more reliable approach. You could do something like `set x to filepath;  set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "/"; last text item of x as integer;` (replace the ; with linefeed) and the result would be `7` and you could get the seventh item from the link list.

Comment: Think I got it!  I found this before I saw your last reply and think it works.  Thanks again for you help!

Comment: `set FolderNumber to input as string
 
 
 -- prefixon run {input, parameters}
 if FolderNumber starts with "Macintosh HD:Users:robdavis:Desktop:!Moms:GDrive Sync:GuestFolders:" then
  set FolderNumber to characters (count of "Macintosh HD:Users:robdavis:Desktop:!Moms:GDrive Sync:GuestFolders::") thru -2 of FolderNumber as string
  -- instead of (count of "~/") you could just use 2
 end if`    New to stack overflow and can't seem to get my code to format correctly---sorry about that!

Comment: Comments aren't supposed to be very formatted but they seem to basically follow the site's markdown. You can also write in the 'answer' text box, format and then copy paste into a comment. Also, you can edit your own question. While you don't want to change what's being asked, you can elaborate. If you work out the solution you want you can then post it as an answer. Another approach: `on run {input, parameters}; set filePath to input as text; set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ":"; set lti to text item -2 of filePath as integer; return lti; end run;`.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do this with AppleScript, but it would be much more sensible to do this with a shell script, by way of the **Run Shell Script** action in Automator, selecting the option to pass the input *`"as arguments"`*.  The default shell in macOS is `zsh`, so stick with that.

The script is short and sweet:

```
( PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
  basename "$1" | bc
) 2>/dev/null
```

**`basename`** extracts last path component, which, in this case, is the name of the folder, even if the path ends with a trailing slash.  The result of this command is then piped through to **`bc`**, which performs basic calculations: this is purely to parse the folder name as a number, so that `"00007"` simply returns `"7"`.

How to make use of this value is entirely dependent on how and where you store the various links from which it selects.  Here's one suggestion, which is reasonably simple:

[image: Screenshot of Automator workflow on macOS]

This allows you to hard-code your 300 or so links into a single *Automator* variable, which a second shell script reads and returns the specific link associated (by line number) with the value obtained from the previous shell script.  The link then placed onto the clipboard.